# Sending PDF/Docx byte array as email attachment

Tags: node.js, express, docusignapi, nodemailer

DocuSign is calling our webhook upon signing of documents. These documents are then stored in a database. They are stored as they are received from DocuSign as PDF bytes which are base64binary encoded. Another server then calls this server to retrieve the documents. I then send the documents as an attachment via nodemailer. After opening the attachment it does not render/decode properly. It displays as the encoded base64 data and not readable text. Can someone kindly point out what I'm doing wrong?

**The response body looks like this:**

`[ { Name: [ 'name-of-doc.docx' ], PDFBytes: [ 'JVBERi0xLjUKJfv8/f4KJVdy ... '] } ]`

**Here's the code:**

```
request(options, function (err, response) {

      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'email@domain.com',
        to: 'email@domain.com',
        subject: "Test",
        html: "This is a test. See attached.",
        attachments:[{
          filename: JSON.parse(response.body).pdfs[0].Name,
          content: JSON.parse(response.body).pdfs[0].PDFBytes[0],
          encoding: 'base64'
          // also have tried new Buffer(...PDFBytes[0], 'base64') in content
        }]
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible double encoding problem.

I suggest that you decode the pdf when you receive it. The base64 encoding used by Connect is just to transport the pdf from the connect system to your app.

Then, encode it again, if needed, for transportation via email.

For email, why not send it as a pdf attachment? (Vs an encoded format?)

I suggest you write a new stack overflow question of "how do I send an email with a pdf attachment using nodemailer"

(Now that I re-read your question, I guess that you're trying to focus on the nodemailer issues. The docusignapi tag tripped me up. You may want to remove that tag since your question is not about DocuSign.)